# Excel - Allow editing from MATLAB while sheet still open

Tags: excel, windows, matlab

I'm trying to create an add-in for Excel with Matlab, where the end goal is to import data and graphs.
I've managed to paste the current figure in Matlab to Excel using the code below:

```
function xlsPasteToCOPY(filename,sheetname,width, height,varargin)
%Paste current figure to selected Excel sheet and cell
%
%
% xlsPasteTo(filename,sheetname,width, height,range)
%Example:
%xlsPasteTo('File.xls','Sheet1',200, 200,'A1')
% this will paset into A1 at Sheet1 at File.xls the current figure with
% width and height of 200
%
% tal.shir@hotmail.com
options = varargin;
range = varargin{1};

[fpath,file,ext] = fileparts(char(filename));
if isempty(fpath)
fpath = pwd;
end
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
set(Excel,'Visible',0);
Workbook = invoke(Excel.Workbooks, 'open', [fpath filesep file ext]);
Workbook.ChangeFileAccess(2);
sheet = get(Excel.Worksheets, 'Item',sheetname);
invoke(sheet,'Activate');
ExAct = Excel.Activesheet;

ExActRange = get(ExAct,'Range',range);
ExActRange.Select;
pos=get(gcf,'Position');
set(gcf,'Position',[ pos(1:2) width height])
print -dmeta
invoke(Excel.Selection,'PasteSpecial');
invoke(Workbook, 'Save');
invoke(Excel, 'Quit');
delete(Excel);
```

However this only works when the said Excel sheet is **closed**. I need a way to allow editing while it's still open. Is this possible?

It works perfectly while the Excel-sheet is closed. But when kept open, I receive this error message:
[image: Error]

Comment: This is how computers work, not how MATLAB works. If two programs open the same file, there is no way to ensure there are no write conflicts. If you edit from excel, it won't show in MATLAB, because MATLAB has already read the file. If you edit from MATLAB, Excel won't show it because Excel has already read the file. Programs works from RAM, they load the data and close the file, and just have the data on RAM. If this was not the case, the "save" button would not exist.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!